# View not loading when called from a Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a controller using **artisan** in my Laravel application, here's the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NavigationController extends Controller {

    public function welcome() {
        return view("welcome");
    }

}
```

When I use a Closure or load the view directly, everything works fine. But, when I load view from inside a controller, it couldn't find it. Here's my ***web.php*** file's code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('NavigationController@welcome');
});
```

The error it shows:

> InvalidArgumentException View [NavigationController@welcome] not found:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the view NavigationController@welcome doesn't exist, this is a method.

Either you load the view from the closure :

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Either you call a method of the controller and this method loads the view:

```
Route::get('/', 'NavigationController@welcome');
```

Please see: [Laravel Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing)